# Azure Logic App - Failed to Fetch Swagger

Tags: azure, azure-api-apps, azure-logic-apps

I have created a SQL connector and am trying to use it within a logic app (trigger) through the "HTTP + Swagger" Managed API from a blank template within the designer.

However after entering the SWAGGER ENDPOINT URL  https://'my-host'.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1 I receive the following error:

Failed to fetch swagger. Ensure you have CORS enabled on the endpoint and are calling an HTTPS endpoint.

I have verified the configuration:

1. SQLconnector->Application Settings->Access Level = Public (anonymous)
2. SQLConnector->Host->API definition = https://'my-host'.azurewebsites.net/swagger/docs/v1
3. SQLconnector->Host->CORS = "*"
4. Restarted the Host

Note that I am able to retrieve Swagger Meta data directly through the browser using the above link.  I can also retrieve data from the API through the browser.

Why does the logic app have the a problem getting the Swagger?

Comment: Did you ever get this resolved?